# EntityFramework update an existing Entity

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

WPF-MVVM-EntityFramework

I have a problem when i'm trying to update an existing entity in a MVMV WPF project
I have a **User** entity on which there is a collection of **UserApplication**

**UserApplication**
ServerId    int 
ApplicationId   int 
UserId          int 
BinDirectory    varchar(MAX)

**User**
Login   varchar(50) 
Id  int

When i'm adding a new application for my user, i need to add a record in my UserApplications table.

In my User model class there is an AddApplication method

```
public void AddApplication (int appId, int serverId, string bin)
{
this.userApplications.add (new UserApplication(){
 ApplicationId = appId,
 ServerId = serverId,
 BinDirectory = bin,
 userId = this.Id
});
}
```

In my **view model** there is the following code

```
this.currentUser.AddApplication(_currentApp.Id, _currentServer.Id, "my_directory");
userDao.Update(this.currentUser);
```

In userDao

```
public int Update(User userToSave)
        {                
            using (Context dpEnt = new Context())
            {
                try
                {
                    dpEnt.Attach(userToSave);
                    return dpEnt.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _log.Error(ex.Message);
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here i have the following exception on the Attach call : An object with a temporary EntityKey value cannot be attached to an object context.

I've also try (userDao)

```
public int Update(UserApplication userApp)
            {                
                using (Context dpEnt = new Context())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        dpEnt.UserApplications.AddObject(userApp);
                        return dpEnt.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        _log.Error(ex.Message);
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here, it also doesn't work

Can you help me please?

Comment: Your first solution can't work because attach does not insert a new Record. What Error do you get with your second solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add the application to the user *after* you have attached the user to the context. Otherwise EF won't recognize the new application:

In userDao you need some method like:

```cs
public int AddApplicationToUser(User userToSave,
    int appId, int serverId, string bin)
{                
    using (Context dpEnt = new Context())
    {
        try
        {
            dpEnt.Attach(userToSave);
            userToSave.AddApplication(appId, serverId, bin);

            return dpEnt.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Error(ex.Message);
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

And then only call:

```cs
userDao.AddApplicationToUser(this.currentUser,
    _currentApp.Id, _currentServer.Id, "my_directory");
```

You can also add directly the new application to the context and save the changes because your application has a correct foreign key property set to the user.